# SQLite case sensitive search with collate nocase field

Tags: sql, sqlite, collation

I have a database (which I cant change) that has a collate nocase field:

```
    name string collate nocase
```

I need to do a search on this field that is case sensitive.  Is this possible with the 'collate nocase'?

Thanks

Comment: you could use a function to test for ASCII values of the string if it wasn't sqlite. there is no built-in function to test ASCII code in sqlite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [switch the collation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#collateop) back for that query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name COLLATE BINARY = 'Nick'
```