# Case sensitive searching

Tags: sql, sqlite, search, wildcard, nspredicate

I am developing an iphone app which uses Sqlite as its backend. I want to implement search functionality in my app and I used sql query for that. I want to implement the searching in a case sensitive manner.I used the following query or fetching data.

```
SELECT data FROM table where data LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Since Sqlite is case insensitive I am getting data starting with 'a' and 'A'. The alternate option to meet my requirement is filter the fetched content within my code before displaying it. I tried NSPredicate for that, but that also works in case insensitive manner.
This is my code..

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[c]  %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[filter characterAtIndex:i]]];
NSArray *arr = [arrayComponent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Your predicate is case insensitive because of the `[c]` option after BEGINSWITH. If you omit that then it searches case sensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE name glob 'A*'
```

see sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/18215/1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you could use a `PRAGMA` statement in your environment, but there is an option as follows:

```
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = true;
```

> The PRAGMA statement is an SQL extension specific to SQLite and used
>   to modify the operation of the SQLite library. When
>   case_sensitive_like is enabled, case becomes significant. So, for
>   example, 'a' LIKE 'A' is false but 'a' LIKE 'a' is still true.

The document is here:
http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like

Answer (score -1):

Found another answer that might help you:

[SQLite case sensitive search with collate nocase field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947945/sqlite-case-sensitive-search-with-collate-nocase-field)

In short you need to change collation using the `COLLATE` command:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#collateop

EDIT Try this (from other post above):

```
SELECT data FROM table where data LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY ID ASC COLLATE BINARY
```

Comment: Collations do not affect the `LIKE` operator.